# Why does the height of the HTML element in the browser developer tools window not reflect its actual height in the browser viewport?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

If we have a body that is larger than the HTML element, then the HTML element is given a scrollbar. Why then is the height of the HTML element still the height as the body, even though it has a scrollbar? It is in fact, not the height of the body, that's why the scrollbar is there in the first place.

I was expecting the height of the HTML element in the devtools window to be the same height as the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

> I was expecting the height of the HTML element in the devtools window to be the same height as the viewport.

That expectation isn't justified. Except when the document is in quirks mode, the default height of the html element is "auto", which means it will be the height of its content.

> If we have a body that is larger than the HTML element, then the HTML element is given a scrollbar.

That's incorrect. The default value of overflow on the html element is "visible", so the remainder of the body is just painted below the bottom of the html element.

A vertical scrollbar appears when there is content to be painted below the height of the viewport, not of the html element.

Comment: If then scrollbar is not of the html element, how come the scrollbar disappears when I add overflow: hidden to the html element in the devtools window?

Comment: @JoelCastro - Because [the overflow setting on the html element is propagated to the viewport.](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css2/#ref-for-propdef-overflow%E2%91%A0%E2%91%A1)